# Acado toolkit matlab installation

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm trying to install *ACADO* Toolkit to use it with *Matlab* and have troubles.
In user manual (page:8) (can be seen [here](http://acado.sourceforge.net/doc/pdf/acado_matlab_manual.pdf)), it says to install *Visual C++* compiler and restart the computer. I did that part. As a second step, it says that write `mex -setup` on *Matlab* and when I did that it gives errors:

> ```
> Error using mex
> No supported compiler or SDK was found. You can install the freely available MinGW-w64 C/C++ compiler; see Install MinGW-w64
> Compiler. For more options, visit http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2016b/win64.html.
> ```

I also tried to install *MinGW-w64* compiler and it wasn't installed and give installation error and said:

> "There was a problem installing the third-party software".

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: which compiler did you isntall? is it compatible with your MATLAB version? Each matlab version has a different set of compatible compilers, you can not just choose one

Comment: I'm using MATLAB 2016b and installed Visual C++ compiler 2015

Comment: Go [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/previous_releases.html) and check if it is a supported compiler. If it is, then `mex -setup` should catch it.

Comment: Please, take more than 5 seconds to read the linked webpage.

Comment: still cannot find. for example for 2017a you can see them in detail like https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.html but for this one not.

Comment: [A small diagram showing where it is](http://imgur.com/u5vQFtZ.png)

Comment: ok. I have matlab2016b in my computer and reinstalled visual c++ 2015 professional. And it still gives the same error.

Comment: Either you did not instal it properly or your MATLAB is broken. Generally is the first one, but the second is possible.